# Jquery Datatable: How can I change the sZeroRecords value after the table has been initialized?

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable that, when there are no records, sometimes should say "Click an item from above" and other times should say "No data available in table".

I can find no way to change the sZeroRecords string after table initialization.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this - or some other technique for getting the same behavior?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Overridden message here"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You might want to explain your answer so the questioner understands what you did.

Comment: Isn't this defining the string at table initialization? I am looking for a way to do this after the table is initially defined.